# ffmpeg export video to 1 image

Tags: ffmpeg, preview

In the process of creating a preview of what ffmpeg, is streaming i came up with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i colony.mkv -c:v libx264 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:1234 -vf fps=1 -s 320x240 d:\preview\out%d.jpg
```

This is great, but it is outputting to a series of image files that are difficult to track:out1.jpg, out2.jpg ... etc...

When i remove the %d parameters, it throws an error saying

```
[image2 @ 00000162c6a3d840] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern 'd:\preview\out.jpg' (either set update or use a pattern like %03d within the filename pattern)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
```

Is there a way to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the update option.

```
-vf fps=1 -s 320x240 -update 1 d:\preview\out.jpg
```

This will rewrite onto the same file.

To avoid a possible read op in the middle of the updating, you can add `-atomic_writing 1`

Comment: Sorry to bother you again .. But with this command when i put a logo (an overlay) it stops generating the preview image any specific reason ?? i am using a filter_complex to overlay the logo as i am using a subtitle also and a banner .. but with everything the preview works except when i use the logo overlay .. it stops generating the preview or the second output

Comment: Open a new Q with the new command

Comment: i did .. just did